# How would I find the variance of a random variable with this distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Random variable $X$ has the following distribution:
$P(X=0) = 1/2$
For all non-zero integers, $P(X=n) = (1/2)^{|n|+2}$

How would I find the variance of this random variable?

I know that the variance can be found by calculating $\operatorname{E}(X^2) - \operatorname{E}(X)^2$ but I am unsure of how to do this since the PMF has two parts. Thanks!

Comment: use the definition of the expectation of $X$, that is $$E[X]:=\sum_{x\in\Omega}x\Pr[X=x]$$ In your case you have that $\Omega =\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Are negative numbers not included?

Comment: @phelhephelhe A random variable cannot be negative.

Comment: @Zizou23 a random variable can take any kind of value, negative, complex, etc...

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I'm trying to see if the function sums to 1. I.e., $S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+2}+\frac{1}{2}$ = $\frac{3}{4}$.So the pmf only sums to 3/4. The function $S=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n+2}$does sum to 1. So I'm not understanding something. Are you sure the definition of the pmf above is correct?

Comment: @PMF the series must be multiplied by $2$.

Comment: Okay so I did the sum from -∞  to -1 of xPr[X=x]  and got -.5, then I did the sum from 1 to ∞ of xPr[X=x] and got .5. Then 0*$(1/2)^{0+2}$ = 0. If you add those up you get 0, so does E(X) = 0?

Comment: @phelhephelhe yes, that is. Now instead of $x$ use $x^2$, that is, in general we have that $$E[f(X)]=\sum_{x\in\Omega}f(x)\Pr[X=x]$$

Comment: @Masacroso - I see - I did not understand the function. Here is what I have now, which does sum to 1. $S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\left| n\right| +2}+\sum _{n=-\infty }^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\left| n\right| +2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$

Comment: So when I used $x^2$ with the same method I get 1.5+0+1.5, so the variance of X is 3, correct? Because $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$ = 3 - 0 = 3.

Comment: @phelhephelhe yes, that is correct.

Comment: @Masacroso awesome, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Since the distribution is symmetric about $0$, $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$. 
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty k^2 2^{-|k|-2} = 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 2^{-k-2} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k$$

Now consider 
\begin{align} 
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k = \frac{1}{1-x} -1 \textrm{ if } |x|<1\\
\Rightarrow x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(x\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^2x^k = \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}
\end{align}
Thus,
$$ \operatorname{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3} \right]_{x=\frac{1}{2}} = 3 = \operatorname{Var}[X]$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I get...

$$f=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{|n| +2}+\frac{1}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{|n| +2}$$

$$E[X]^2= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{ |n| +2} + 0\cdot\frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{|n|+2}=0$$
and

$$E[X^2]=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} n ^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{|n| +2}+ 0^2 \cdot\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \ n ^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{|n|+2} = 3 $$

So,

$$V[X]=E[X^2]-E[X]^2=3-0=3.$$